# What word means several descriptive words?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

I thought it was descriptor, but apparently that's not an actual word.

Comment: _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) has an entry for _descriptor_, which it dates to 1933 and defines as "something (as a word or characteristic feature) that serves to describe or identify; _esp_ **:** a word or phrase (as an index term ( used to identify an item (as a subject or document) in an information retrieval system." So if that's the meaning you have in mind, you're all set with _descriptor_.

Answer (score 1):

The word you may be looking for is *descriptors*
Sorry haha that is the correct word just make it plural and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

You could try "blurb": "a short description that praises something (such as a book) so that people will want to buy it" ([m-w.com](http://m-w.com/dictionary/blurb)).

"Epitaph" might also work: "a brief statement commemorating or epitomizing a deceased person or something past" ([m-w.com](http://m-w.com/dictionary/epitaph), sense 2).

"Summary" is getting further afield: "a brief statement that gives the most important information about something" ([m-w.com](http://m-w.com/dictionary/summary)).